# How do I turn this into LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

How will convert my SQL into LINQ?

```
DECLARE @cookie nvarchar(50)

SET @cookie = 'test@test.com'

SELECT s.firstname
FROM [examManager].[dbo].[students] AS s
JOIN [examManager].[dbo].tutors t ON s.last_exam IN (t.default_exam_id ,      
t.last_exam, t.next_exam)
OR s.next_exam IN (t.default_exam_id , t.last_exam , t.next_exam)
--WHERE t.email = @cookie
```

I am going down this route (below query) but it's not bringing back what I need when compare to the SQL results. I'll handle the cookie in the C# that's not an issue.

```
var tStudents = from s in student
                join t in tutor on s.last_exam equals t.default_exam_id //{ ColA = s.last_exam, ColB = s.next_exam } equals new { ColA = t.last_exam, ColB = t.next_exam }
                join t2 in tutor on s.last_exam equals t2.last_exam
                join t3 in tutor on s.last_exam equals t3.next_exam
                //where t.email == finalCookie
                select new
                {
                    s.firstname,
                    s.lastname,
                };
```

+++EDIT+++
For the above to work please consider these two sample tables.

Tutors

```
------------------------------------------------------------
id    |email |        |default_exam_id| |last_exam|next_exam
------------------------------------------------------------
0     |test@test.com  |903              |910      |903
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Students

```
------------------------------------------------------------
id    |fname |        |last_exam        |next_exam
------------------------------------------------------------
0     |john           |903              |910      
1     |doe            |912              |903      
2     |gary com       |909              |988      
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result/s should be as follows:

```
0     |john           |903              |910      
1     |doe            |912              |903
```

Comment: i don't even know that such SQL is possible :)

Comment: Can you add an example of your data set and what data you would want to return? Just so we have a fuller picture.

Comment: In terms of data @nbokmans what is returned is a JSON obj by doing this:                       return Json(new { data = data, tStudents = tStudents }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); and then on the client it's a Datatable that's is displayed to the user. But as far as my understanding goes this irrelevant as I should see back my rows in the tStudents obj once the LINQ is executed and the client is not concerned in this stage.

Comment: Your condition in the ON caluse could be entirely in the WHERE clause.

Comment: No i mean right now I'm not sure what your desired result is. Can you formulate your query into a sentence?

Comment: Yes. Select all students who belong to a given tutor based on tutors default exam or last exam or next exam matching a student's last exam or next exam.

Comment: I'll give @jannagy02 suggestion a try ;-)

Comment: @Shucoder I tried to wrute answer but I dont have your C# classes so cannot test it . Please give a try I hope it helps . Also it will be better if you paste your classes in order to understand question easily .

Comment: Please see the edit guys. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension to my comment:

I think that putting the condition in the where clause semantically is more correct also.

```
var tStudents = from s in student
                from t in tutor
                where (s.last_exam == t.default_exam_id || s.last_exam == t.last_exam || s.last_exam == t.next_exam
                || s.next_exam == t.default_exam_id || s.next_exam == t.last_exam || s.next_exam == t.next_exam)
                //&& t.email == finalCookie
                select new
                {
                    s.firstname,
                    s.lastname,
                };
```

Update:

```
var result = tStudents.Distinct();
```

Comment: This brought back too many rows. Please see my edit in original post.

Comment: @Shucoder Maybe you only need to add Distinct(). I edited the post.

Comment: Unfortunately no. The results are cut shorter but it's not the correct results also I was already aware of Distinct results and the method. Did you see my example table? I think the confusing thing here is the Student's table has one less column but I'm sure it's been done before.

Comment: @Shucoder Does your SQL query provide the right result set? (this linq should provide the same)

Comment: I take my previous comment back @jannagy02 ! Your answer was correct! I was just missing my cookie and after lunch I spotted that and now it all works exactly as expected and correct rows are return in LINQ ....happy days.

Comment: Apologies yes it does and your LINQ query brought back the correct result too!

Answer (score 0):

Is this even anything remotely close to what you want? I tried my best going from your description in the comments of the OP.

```
List<string> students =
    studentList.Where(
            s =>
                tutorList.Any(
                    t =>
                        t.last_exam == s.last_exam || t.next_exam == s.last_exam ||
                        t.default_exam_id == s.last_exam || t.last_exam == s.next_exam ||
                        t.next_exam == s.next_exam || t.default_exam_id == s.next_exam))
        .Select(n => n.firstname + " " + n.lastname)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This was the closest results to my queries but still few too many and a few wrong results too. Please see my edit in original post which should help everyone by showing the result tables.